# Need help on snake program about user's input

Tags: python, tkinter, input, tkinter-canvas

So, I'm writing a snake program using the tkinter Library. The program is globally working but I have a little problem with the inputs' treatment indeed if i give two input too quickly only the last one will be interpret. And i don't really know how to solve this i try to force the update after every player's input but it's clearly not the good solution because it force the snake to move and make it able to teleport so I'm would be glad if someone has an idea to solve this issue. There is my code I'm sure that it could be improved but for now I would like to focus on the first issue.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy.random as rd

class snake:
    def __init__(self,n,m):
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
        self.body = [(n//2,m//2),(n//2,m//2-1)]
        self.lenght = 2
        self.food = (0,0)
        self.relocate_food()
        self.Game = -2
        self.vector = (0,1)  #(0,-1) = up, (0,1) = right, (0,1) = down, (-1,0) = left
        self.speed = 120

    def up(self):
        self.vector = (-1,0)  
    def right(self):
        self.vector = (0,1) 
    def down(self):
        self.vector = (1,0)      
    def left(self):
        self.vector = (0,-1)


    def relocate_food(self):
        x = rd.randint(0,self.n)
        y = rd.randint(0,self.m)
        i = 0
        test = True
        while i<self.lenght and test:
            if (x,y) == self.body[i]:
                test = False
                self.relocate_food()
            else:
                i += 1
        if i == self.lenght:
            self.food = (x,y)


    def collide(self):
        head = self.body[0]
        for i in range(1,self.lenght):
            if head == self.body[i]:
                self.Game = -1
                break
            x,y = head
            if x>=self.n or y>=self.m or x<0 or y<0:
                self.Game = -1

    def eat(self):
        head = self.body[0]
        if head == self.food:           
            self.lenght +=1
            x0, y0 = self.body[-1]
            x1, y1 = self.body[-2]
            x = x0 - x1
            y = y0 - y1
            self.body.append((x0+x,y0+y))
            self.relocate_food()
            if self.lenght%5 == 0:
                self.speed = int(self.speed * 0.90)




    def move(self):
        dx, dy = self.vector     
        last_x, last_y = self.body[0]
        new_x = last_x + dx
        new_y = last_y + dy
        self.body[0] = (new_x, new_y)
        for k in range(1, self.lenght):
            x, y = self.body[k]
            self.body[k] = (last_x,last_y)
            last_x, last_y = x, y
        return 




class screen(snake):
    def __init__(self,root,n,m):
        snake.__init__(self,n,m)
        root.minsize(n*20,m*20)
        root.maxsize(n*20,m*20)
        root.configure(background='white')
        self.root = root
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
        self.speed = 130
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = n*20, height =m*20,bg='black')
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Key-Up>",self.move_up)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Key-Down>",self.move_down)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Key-Left>",self.move_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Key-Right>",self.move_right)
        self.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.draw_snake()
        self.draw_food()


    def draw_snake(self):
        y,x = self.body[0]
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x*20,y*20,(x+1)*20,(y+1)*20,fill= 'red4')
        for k in range(1,self.lenght):
            y,x = self.body[k]
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x*20,y*20,(x+1)*20,(y+1)*20,fill= 'red')

    def draw_food(self):
        y,x =self.food
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x*20,y*20,(x+1)*20,(y+1)*20,fill= 'green')

    def move_up(self,event):
        if self.Game == -2:
            self.Game =0
            self.up()
            self.update()
        else:
            self.up()


    def move_down(self,event):
        if self.Game == -2:
            self.Game =0
            self.down()
            self.update()
        else:
            self.down()

    def move_left(self,event):
        if self.Game == -2:
            self.Game =0
            self.left()
            self.update()
        else:
            self.left()

    def move_right(self,event):
        if self.Game == -2:
            self.Game =0
            self.right()
            self.update()
        else:
            self.right()


    def update(self):
        if self.Game == -2:
            return 
        self.move()
        self.eat()
        self.collide()
        if self.Game == -1:
            self.root.destroy()
            return 
        self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.draw_snake()
        self.draw_food()
        self.root.after(self.speed,self.update)

window = tk.Tk()
snake = screen(window,35,35)
snake.update()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: standard rule : if you have many elements then keep them on list. It seems you have variable to keep only one input so last input replaces previous one before code could use it to move snake. You have to add new input to the end of some list and later code has to use `for`-loop to use all inputs from list to move snake.

Comment: With `self.update()` from any key event handler you are doing **concurrent** updates. Remove all `self.update()`, `__init__` with `self.Game = 0` is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank Furas for the basic idea it was what i needed. New code with my correction :

```
def __init__(self, root,n,m):
"""

    """
    self.input = []

"""


     """
def move_up(self,event):
    if self.Game == -2:
        self.Game =0
        self.up()
        self.update()
    else:
        self.input.append(0)

"""
    Same for all the move
    """


def update(self):
    if self.Game == -2:
        return 
    if len(self.input)>3: #Make sure that the player doesn't stack instruction
        self.pop()
    try:
        input = self.input.pop(0)
    except:
        input = -1
    if input == 0:
        self.up()
    elif input == 1:
        self.right()
    elif input == 2:
        self.down()
    elif input == 3:
        self.left()
    self.move()
    self.eat()
    self.collide()
    if self.Game == -1:
        self.root.destroy()
        return 
    self.canvas.delete("all")
    self.draw_snake()
    self.draw_food()
    self.root.after(self.speed,self.update)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a bug. Your animation uses an 'update' function that is executed every 120ms. So if you hit 2 arrow keys within 120ms (i.e. between two successive calls of 'update'), only the last hit is considered, because only one translation vector can be considered for each snake update. Nobody can blame you on that point, as time controlled animation is a discrete process with a given time window. It's the only solution to get fluid and regular animation (all video games are based on such a process), so that's clearly correct.

However, your code may still be improved on several aspects. For instance, at each animation frame, you delete all Canvas items and create a whole new set of items ('create_rectangle') for the snake elements and the food. This is not very efficient. It would be better to simply change the coordinates of the items (check the Canvas.coords function from the doc). Note that animating a snake simply requires to move the previous tail position to the new head position, to give the illusion of a moving beast. So moving only 1 item (2 items when eating food) is necessary at each frame, which is must faster to process.

Comment: Thank for the idea of improvement I will try that